# On a master page I add <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" it disappears when I "ViewSource

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I am running SharePoint 2013 (October CU).

in master page my first line is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I want to add a print css file so I add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="........"  media="print" />
```

When I open a page and right click and select "View Source" the `<link rel=......./>` is there, but the `media="print"` is missing.  I want to use this when a user prints a page !

Anybody any ideas ?

Comment: Internet explorer 11?

Comment: I'm assuming `SP2013` was referring to SharePoint. Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry - yes Internet Explorer 11 is being used